# How to block page access via url if not logged in?

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc

I have implemented a login page with Java and Spring mvc.
"index.html"
THe problem now is that you can easily get around it by just calling /person.html and you´re into the application.

How can I prevent this without having to use Spring Security?

Comment: set username in session. Check in your jsp if the username is null redirect to login page

Comment: Implementing security is not a trivial task. Spring security is made for this reason why not use it? What is the problem with using spring security?

Comment: @RaviH. I simply dont have time to implement it (I spend 3 days already earlier trying to get it up). My application is already delayed.

Comment: @Sembrano There  you go. By trying to avoid spring security you are wrapping yourself into more problem. Spring security has good documentation. Follow the documentation. Get some help from the community. You will be in far better position than trying to implement a rudimentary security implementation putting you in numerous other problems down the line.

Comment: Shouldnt be needed. When we read security in School we never used it. We just used prepared statements and hashed + salted all pw´s and we implemented our own login aswell to block access page I cant remeber really. I must have missed that lesson.. It worked fine took only a few hours compared to Spring Security that is very hard to get up running with all the configs etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Very basic answer.**

Create an interceptor class that extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter. In the preHandle method check if the user exists in session and return true only if the user exists in session.

```
public class AuthenticationCheckInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        //Check if user exists in session. 
        //If no, redirect to login page using response.sendRedirect() and return false
        //If yes, return true
    }
}
```

Apply this interceptor to all URLs which require you to be logged-in.

A simple example is at http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/